# How do I click a button in a java toolbar which is not created by me?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, autoit, uitoolbar

Let me first show you the screenshot of the java toolbar. For proprietary reasons I cannot provide you the url of the site. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Now the focus is to click the 'Exclaim' button. I am using Python here. I am also certain selenium is not able to detect it as it is a toolbar and its corresponding html is not present. I was trying to use AutoIT here but its finder tool is not detecting it. I do not want to use scripts like Sikuli here as it would be a daring venture owing to its instability.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problems I use to solve them with **pyautogui**

Here are the docs: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

This code will find an image on screen and move the mouse to image center:

```
imports pyautogui
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('YOURIMAGE.png', confidence=0.8)
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
```

I've heard some people is getting better results with OpenCV but you can always test